# Storing top 3 rows based on highest value from mysql table in another table

Tags: mysql

I'd like to select top 3 players for the day based on column `RACES` from table `RACERS` and store them somewhere else, as a cron job will delete the entire table at midnight each day.

Answer (score 1):

Just do an `insert into ... select`, like so:

```
insert into table daily_winners(win_date, first_place, second_place, third_place)
select
    now(), 
    (select user from racers order by races limit 1),
    (select user from racers order by races limit 1 offset 1),
    (select user from racers order by races limit 1 offset 2)
)
```

See [Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html), [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax, and the 'limit clause' documentation inside of [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Note that this may have specific performance characteristics in MySQL that might make it undesirable; you'll probably want to do some research on that using the aforementioned documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that and how the script will know who's the first one to add specific reward and who's the second one for example? That's what I want to do ...

Comment: The first one is the first row - because of "order by". I'm not sure what you mean by "separate them" in this context.

Comment: Okay, I will select top 3 and I am aware of that. But how I can do it like: if top 1 row --> query | if top 2 row --> query and etc ? I need to add different prizes to top 3 players. That's what I mean

Comment: Perhaps what you're trying to do is record the daily winners in a permanent way, when you're going to reset the table daily?

Comment: Yes, it will be restarted via cron at 00:00 every day but before that there must be script adding the prizes which are different for top 3 players

Comment: Honestly, it might be easier to just store the date of the races, and not be constantly resetting that table, then use a WHERE clause on the earlier query to limit it to the top three races in a given day - something to think about as you develop your application.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will give it a try in this way and do some tests.